# How to iterate through list in Python/Jython (like with HashMaps)?

Tags: python, list, loops, jython

is there any way to iterate through python/jython lists like in HashMaps?

Example:

```
list = [effectone, effecttwo, effectthree, effectfour]
if list.hasNext():
#do something
```

This is how I done it in hashmaps:

```
       it = channelList.entrySet().iterator() #channelList is an hashmap
       if it.hasNext():
            inext = it.next()
            nextkey = inext.getKey() #Also, how do I get current "effect"?
            nextvalue = inext.getValue()
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you're trying to do is only work with "pairs" of data, ie: where the "next element" has a "next element", then:

```
for cur, nxt in pairwise('abc'):
    print cur, 'and', nxt
```

Gives you:

```
a and b
b and c
```

Adapt to do whatever you need to do on the objects each iteration.

Where `pairwise` is the recipe from the [Python itertools documentation](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#recipes) as such:

```
def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return izip(a, b)
```